# Can I / How do I listen to an external port using wireshark?

Tags: port, wireshark, graylog

I am trying to test my gray logging infrastructure and to do so, I am testing whether my application is sending packets to the correct port mapped to graylog. Since these packets are UDP, I do not receive any ACK to verify if the port has successfully accepted/received my packets. I am now trying to listen to the peer port using wireshark. Is this even possible? Can I listen to a particular port that is not being used by my machine? If so how can I achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: The easiest way is to install `tshark` or `dumpcap` on your app or graylog severs, then take a capture there and copy the file the `pcap` file to your workstation. Another solution is to use a switch that supports `port mirroring` between your app and graylog servers, connect your workstation to this switch and capture in `promiscuous` mode.

Comment: This is the best solution. Thank You!